# StreamWebSocketError api_key not found, data

Tags: firebase, flutter, api, getstream-io

I'm new to flutter and i am trying to run a chat app with getstream and firebase but i keep running into errors [error im running into](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRNqf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your API Key is correctly entered in your code. From your [Stream Dashboard](http://dashboard.getstream.io) you can access your Stream app's API Key and Secret. It might be that the key you're entering is for a Stream app that was deleted, or there is a typo.

Make sure that the API key for your APP there matches exactly with what you pass into your Stream client:

```dart
final client = StreamChatClient(
  'YOUR-KEY', // Make sure this is correct.
  logLevel: Level.INFO,
);
```

I noticed in the screenshot you shared that you also have a `kSecretStreamKey` in your code base. Your secret key is not meant to be used in your Flutter (frontend) application. The secret key is needed to perform sensitive operations on your server (backend) - for example, generating user frontend auth tokens. If you include the secret key in your Flutter codebase, you risk a malicious actor retrieving it by decompiling your application. Your Secret Key is the equivalent of a password.

I recommend taking a look at the Stream Flutter tutorial page if you're still stuck: https://getstream.io/chat/flutter/tutorial/

Or the Stream Flutter YouTube Playlist: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pO_MOJRqYlk&list=PLNBhvhkAJG6t-BxkRAnSqa67lm5C1mpKk